# Is there a specific word for "causing someone to faint"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word describing when somebody makes someone faint without using anaesthesia or physical contact. As seen in some comedy movies where an answer usually causes somebody to lose consciousness.

Comment: *Knock unconscious*? Literally/metaphorically. *Stun*; *Daze*.

Comment: Neck-pinch :) ... - Also I fixed _loose_ for you - http://theoatmeal.com/comics/misspelling

Comment: _Overcome_ is sometimes used. e,g, _I was overcome by the fumes_. But to say _Fred overcame Bill_. wouldn't work.

Comment: @ermanen Is it?  I've never heard *faint* used transitively.

Comment: Kartik: No comments on my answer? It is one word and regardless of what some think they know, it has been used to the exact effect you are looking for

Comment: The medical term for fainting is *syncope,* but unfortunately (per OED) neither of the cognate verbs *syncopate* and *syncopize* has the requisite transitive sense.

Answer (score 5):

[Stupefy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stupefied) seems to fit your requirements. It is a single transitive verb that comes closest to knock someone out.

> 1. to put into a state of little or no sensibility; benumb the faculties of; put into a stupor.
> 2. to stun, as with a narcotic, a shock, or a strong emotion.
> 3. to overwhelm with amazement; astound; astonish.

as in

> He stupefied her with his next statement. She sank to the floor in shock when he told her he was her father

**Note to downvoter**

Although having the same root, stupor is not stupid:

[**stupor** (Oxford dictionaries)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stupor)

> noun *a state of near-unconsciousness or insensibility.
>   "a drunken stupor"*
>
> synonyms:  daze, state of stupefaction, state of senselessness, state of unconsciousness; inertia, torpor, insensibility, numbness, blankness, oblivion, coma, blackout; Scottish dwam

Even Harry Potter agrees -

[***Stupefy***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spells_in_Harry_Potter#Stupefy_.28Stunning_Spell.2C_Stupefying_Charm.2C_Stunner.29) (from Wikipedia, list of spells)

> (Stunning Spell, Stupefying Charm, Stunner)
>   Pronunciation: /ˈstjuːpɨfaɪ/ stew-pi-fy
>
> *Description*: Puts the victim in an unconscious state. Manifests as a jet of red light.
>
> *Seen/mentioned*: First seen in Goblet of Fire, used by Ministry officials at the Quidditch World Cup and later against Barty Crouch Jr.. Also seen used by a number of Ministry officials against McGonagall in Order of the Phoenix. It is also taught by Harry in his Dumbledore's Army meetings and used extensively during the Battle of the Department of Mysteries against the Death Eaters. Is seen by some, including Harry himself, as the basic spell for fighting. Death Eaters, Ministry Officials, Order members and students all seem to refer to this spell as their preferred attack.

Comment: To stupefy is to make someone *stupid* with disbelief. It has nothing to do with unconsciousness.

Comment: Although having the same root, stupor is not stupid: **stupor**
noun _a state of near-unconsciousness or insensibility.
"a drunken stupor"_
synonyms: _daze, state of stupefaction, state of senselessness, state of unconsciousness;_

Comment: I an a few centuries behing the times: "stupid retained its association with stupor and its overtones of 'stunned by surprise, grief, etc.' into mid-18c." I still think of someone being stunned stupid. In either case, it is not a cause of unconsciousness. Only the very worst stupor is associated with altered level of consciousness, but not *unconsciousness*. A deep stupor is a level above unconscious.

Comment: Seriously? Two downvotes for the word that comes the closest to what OP asks?

Answer (score 2):

You might describe someone as having a "syncopal power" over someone else. I don't think there is a word which describes the effector of syncope but I'm sure a portmanteau could be coined if you really have an application for such a word.

Answer (score 1):

As a single word, *daze* can be used in this sense.

[Example](http://books.google.ca/books?id=A96nh5mPKdwC&pg=PT797&dq#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Percy Phelps sank back in his chair. 'My head whirls,' said he; 'your words have dazed me.'

---

It is not a single word but you can consider *make someone swoon*.

[Example:](http://books.google.ca/books?id=RAVA3z_F-L0C&pg=PA63&dq=%22made%20me%20swoon%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zYqGU4n3Kaqh8QGrm4DICQ&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22made%20me%20swoon%22&f=false)

> Then one morning in late August, 1947, I got a phone call from Bob. My blood pressure must have gone up 100 degrees. Just hearing his voice again made me swoon.

---

*[Faint](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/define/Faint)* is (or was) a transitive verb also but the usage is obsolete:

> To cause to faint or become dispirited; to depress; to weaken.
>
> *« It faints me to think what follows.» Shak.*

Answer (score 1):

- to knock out
- to stupefy
- to stun
- to cause to black out

Comment: Can you please show me a usage?

Comment: Is this not just a list of what has already been posted?

Comment: To knock out: The pungent smell drifting up from the corpse knocked her out.

Comment: To stupefy= this word doesn't exactly express the same meaning fainting has, as stupefying someone or something as well a stunning a person or a creature  implies putting the subject into a hazy sort of state, making them slightly less aware or subduing them.

Comment: Peter had one too many shots and blacked out in the door way.

Comment: For example becoming stunned implies that one becomes shocked in the event of either being momentarily yet instantly slowed down or receiving such a thing as a powerful blow in the head that causes confusion, being bewildered etc. It can also be used as an adjective to describe a visual or other quality such as: That dress looks stunning!, The teacher was stunned by the intelligence of the student, but in this case it is better to use astounded or astonished, because here the word "stun" seems to serve more as an adjective more suited for describing the teacher's physical state not mental.

Answer (score -2):

How about [**knock someone out**](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=l_LxuR1jMVgC&pg=PA255&lpg=PA255&dq=knock+cold+idiom&source=bl&ots=YF7-lKNLrx&sig=1Sf7-5b787nT_lnyZYB1zEIIUis&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=wuuFU6yKJYLG0QXn7YHQAQ&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=knock%20cold%20idiom&f=false) (cold)?

> knock someone out : to render unconscious by a blow or some other means

Alternately, consider *make someone [**black out**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/black+out)* and *make someone [**keel over**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/keel_over)*.

> black out: to lose consciousness temporarily: *blacked out at the podium*
>
> keel over: to collapse in a faint

Comment: Two of these answers have been given by another user. *To keel over* is unique, but is more readily understood as "to die" than "to faint".

Comment: @KitFox. No, this is just a copy of a deleted answer [see mplungjan's comment under the other user's answer]. I can reopen the deleted one if you want to.

Comment: It depends on why you deleted the other one, if it is identical to this one.

Comment: @KitFox I'll delete this one and reopen the other so you can see for yourself.